# Restoring auto-renewable subscriptions after

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

We are using auto-renewable subscriptions, and it works ok except for the one edge case.

If user reset their iPhone to the factory settings, it's not possible for them to restore auto-renewable subscription in our app (or so it seems, we have just two such cases now).

We are using SwiftyStoreKit, but I believe that there is a logic error on our side.

Right now we are restoring purchases this way:

```
func checkOldSubscriptions()->Bool {

     //validator
     let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: ss)

      for i in 0..<products.count {

           //checking every available product in receipt
           SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, completion: { (result) in
               switch result {
                   case .success(let receipt):

                let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(
                    type: .autoRenewable, 
                    productId: products[i].name,
                    inReceipt: receipt)

                    switch purchaseResult {
                        case .purchased(let expiresDate):
                        print("Product is valid until \(expiresDate)")

       ...
       }
       }
```

My hypothesis is that after the reset we just don't have any receipt to verify, and I have to retrieve it directly. It's kind of hard to check on device because, honestly, I don't have a real test device that would be easy to kill for me.

So I want to add something like that (manually refreshing the receipt before trying to verifying it):

```
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receipt):
```

Does it make any sense? Will it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. A receipt is not likely to be available after a reset.
You need to call restoreCompletedTransactions() on SKPaymentQueue to retrieve any transactions that were previously marked completed.

Since you are using SwiftyStoreKit you can use SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases. Check the documentation for details.

Comment: Are you sure `restoreCompletedTransactions()` works for subscriptions and not just non-consumables?

Comment: thanks, but actually it means that I'm wrong, and forceRefresh wouldn't help me, and I have to restorePurchases instead. I wanted to escape this because we are selling autorenewable subscriptions (and restorePurchases returns all purchases, included expired ones), but it seems that I don't have any choice here.

Comment: You were right in that you don't have a receipt to verify ;) Restore should, of course, include expired purchases since your customer did pay for that wk/mo/yr. If your business logic doesn't care about expired purchases just mark them completed and move on. The only other valid way to do this would be to manage the user's entitlement on your backend.